# Flexbox item stacking on top of each other IE 10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

So I have this stripped down codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGmeEw

```
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-item">
    <div class="causes-error">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span>I want to receive weekly newsletters</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group-item">
    <div class="causes-error">
      <label >
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span>I agree to terms and conditions</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="input-group m-align-start">
  <div class="input-group-item">
    <div class="causes-error">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span>I want to receive weekly newsletters</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group-item">
    <div class="causes-error">
      <label >
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span>I agree to terms and conditions</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

@import "bourbon";

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@mixin flexbox-value-width($width) {
  @include flex(0 0 $width);

  max-width: $width;
}

.input-group {
  @include display(flex);
  @include flex-wrap(wrap);
  @include justify-content(space-between);
}

.input-group-item {
  @include flexbox-value-width(100%);
  @include flex(1);
}

.input-group.m-align-start {
  @include justify-content(flex-start);
}

.input-group.m-align-start .input-group-item {
  @include flex(0 1 auto);
}

.causes-error {
  @include display(flex);
  @include align-items(center);
}

label {
  @include display(flex);
  @include align-items(center);
  @include flex(1 0 0px);
}
```

The top group of checkboxes render fine in Chrome, FireFox, and IE 10  however the second group of checkboxes does not render properly in IE 10 (Chrome and FireFox render them fine).  The issue in IE 10 is that they are stacking on top of each other and I am not sure why.  I have narrowed the issue down to the div with the `class` of `causes-error`.  If I commit out the css for that element, IE 10 will render it fine (with them right next to each other like the other browsers with that css) however I need that css in the full version of this code (which is way too big to post here, which is way I have this stripped down version).

Does anyone know why IE 10 would be messing this up?

Answer (score 0):

[IE10 only gives partial support to flex](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) by requiring the prefix -ms- and follows the older 2012 syntax.

Comment: Which is why I am using bourbon (unless there is a specific reason why this specific example does not work with the 2012 syntax).